# Повторный GET запрос к картинке при перелистывании слайдера в браузере firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

При перелистывании слайдера firefox заново грузит картинку из кэша, из-за это растёт количество и размер запросов к серверу. Как с этим бороться, чтобы браузер не отправлял каждый раз новый запрос? Данная проблема наблюдается только в браузере firefox.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы сами себе противоречите... " грузит картинку из кэша" ......и "растёт количество и размер запросов к серверу" ..... как ? если берётся из кэша

Comment: При перелистывании слайдера отправляется запрос 200 GET к картинке, при это написано, что кэшировано

Comment: Смотрите код слайдера, вполне вероятно, что под `ff` в нем что-то в `css` или даже `js` написано отдельно.